# Magento disable cache only for cms pages

Tags: magento

My requirement is to disable cache only for cms pages. So is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852167/disable-full-page-caching-for-specific-block

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite / modify `Mage_Cms_PageController` models `preDispatch` method.

```
public function preDispatch() {
    $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();

    // Tell Magento to 'ban' the use of FPC, can also ban other types such as 'block_html'
    $cache->banUse('full_page');

    parent::preDispatch();
}
```

The better, cleaner and safer option than rewriting this controller is to use observers, these look at these events:

```
controller_action_predispatch
controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getRequest()
controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()
```

See [Disable/Bypass Magento Full Page Cache on single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405232/disable-bypass-magento-full-page-cache-on-single-page) for more information.

Comment: @MageAkash are you really using FPC ?

Comment: You can block any type of caching like this though not just `full_page` eg `block_html`